# Finding minimum sum of graph edge weight?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have been given a undirected weighted graph, witch represents the road with junctions. The task is in every cycle, which begins and ends in a same vertex choose the edge with the lowest weight and calculate the sum of all these edges in graph.

Idea is to use Prim algorithm, but there is a chance that some cycles doesn't include edge from MST.

How to solve this problem, and how to modify Prim's algorithm?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you plan on using Prim's for this?

Comment: This was suggested by someone else who apparently have done this. I don't know!

Comment: Interesting problem, but the question as such is bad. You should have a look at the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)